# django get_object() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given) with custom feeds

Tags: python, django, feed

I'm following the custom Feed example in the book Learning Website Development with Django and learn the necessary changes from old version to Django 1.7.

The feed class i got is:

```
class UserBookmarks(Feed):

    def get_object(self,bits):
        if len(bits) != 1:
            raise ObjectDoesNotExist
        return User.objects.get(username=bits[0])

    def title(self,user):
        return 'Django Bookmarks | Bookmarks for %s' % user.username

    def link(self,user):
        return '/feeds/user/%s/' % user.username

    def description(self,user):
        return 'Recent bookmarks posted by %s' % user.username

    def items(self,user):
        return user.bookmark_set.order_by('-id')[:10]
```

And the url configurations:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
      url(r'^feeds(\w*)/$',UserBookmarks()),
)
```

When I refresh the site, Django gives me a TypeError:
get_object() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

I can't figure out where the issue is... please help!

Comment: Upload the code that calls `get_object()` (and gets error)

Comment: @DRC's answer will fix your immediate problem, but I strongly recommend you use a different book to learn Django. 'Learning Website Development with Django' is from 2008. There have been many changes in Django since then. For example, the changes to the syndication feed framework that are causing you problems here are from Django 1.2 in 2010.

Comment: Thank you Alasdiar, Is there any good book you could recommend?

Comment: @browser it's been a few years since I learned Django, so I don't really have any current recommendations. The official tutorial is the best place to start if you haven't worked through it already. [Two Scoops](http://twoscoopspress.org/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-6) is a good intermediate book. [Tango with Django](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/) seems to be quite popular, but I haven't read it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update the get_object signature to

```
def get_object(self, request, bits):
```